# Is this a q-count of Alternating Sign Matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, q-analogs

The number of Alternating Sign Matrices of size $n$ is well known to be
$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(3k+1)!}{(n+k)!}$. Is it known whether the naive q-analog expression
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{[3k+1]_q!}{[n+k]_q!}$$
is a polynomial in $q$ with positive coefficients? Does it come from a known statistic on ASM's?

Comment: If I computed right then at least for $n \leq 20$ it's a polynomial in $n$ with coefficients that are not just positive but unimodal.  For example, $n=7$ gives $[1, 6, 20, 49, 98, 169, 259, 359, 455, 531, 573, 573, 531, 455, 359, 259, 169, 98, 49, 20, 6, 1]$.

Comment: I do not get unimodality: n=4 gives for example [1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1]

Comment: Can someone please provide the q-expressions for n=1..4?

Comment: My computation for n=4 agrees with the one by @PerAlexandersson.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I'm a bit puzzled, I get something very different for $n=7$: a polynomial of degree 112 with leading coefficients $1,0,1,1,2,3,5,\dots$.  For $n=4$ I have precisely what Per Alexandersson has.

Comment: For the associated cyclic sieving phenomenon see http://www.math.umn.edu/~reiner/REU/CloningerDavidowitz2007.pdf

Answer (score 10):

It's true these polynomials are not unimodal for n=2 and up, since they all start with coefficient sequence 1 0 1 ... (The reason for this is clear from the definition of descending plane partitions.) For n = 4, 5, 6, they are also non-unimodal in the middle. But the sequence of nonzero coefficients seems to be unimodal for n=7 and above (I've calculated up to n=35). I had observed the non-unimodality of n=4,5,6 several years ago, but had thought it would continue to fail, so it's interesting to me that it seems to be (nearly-)unimodal at n=7 and beyond.

When the ASM is a permutation matrix, the right statistic is a weighted inversion count: weight each inversion pair by the larger number in the pair and then add up all the contributions. (See [St000616](http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000616/) on [FindStat](http://www.findstat.org).) The generating function for this statistic on permutations is an interesting analogue of the q-factorial. (See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3391v2.pdf Corollary 6.)

I also think looking at the Gog or Magog triangles to try and find the right statistic is a good idea, but it's not one of the usual statistics, as far as I can tell. I've thought about this question quite a lot and would be very interested if anyone is able to make progress on finding this statistic on ASM or TSSCPP.

Comment: Hi Jessica, welcome to MathOverflow!

As a tangent, perhaps there is a nice generalization of inv and maj to ASMs, that are equidistributed, and thus give an analogue of Mahonian-ness for ASMs.

Comment: Hi @Per, yes that would be quite nice. There is a generalization of inv to ASMs; the trouble is there are some choices to make and it's not known what the _right_ choice is. (See [St000332](http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000332/) and [St000067](http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000067/)). You can come up with a generalization of maj too [St000227](http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000227), but it's not equidistributed with either of the previous statistics, so none of these statistics seem to be exactly what you would want.

Comment: Mapping to SSYTs gives the possibility to compute charge, which is Mahonian on permutations. Perhaps that could be something..

Answer (score 4):

The naive $q$-analog of that expression is naturally a generating function for descending plane partitions by weight (not sure of reference, though), but it doesn't translate to any natural statistic on ASMs/monotone triangles/etc., and it's not known what statistic on ASMs does the trick.

In terms of unimodality, I would imagine there's a way to prove it algebraically by induction. There's a trick along the lines of 'If $f(q)$ is unimodal, and $f(q)/[n]_q$ is a polynomial, then $f(q)/[n]_q$ is also unimodal.' that might work.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is more natural to look at Gog or Magog-triangles,
which are special types of GT-patterns, equinumerous with ASMs.

These GT-patterns can then be mapped to SSYTs of triangle shape,
and on these, one can do lots of statistics.

I tried a few, but no obvious candidate.

EDIT:

This questing has been asked in the end of [this article (notices  of the AMS)](http://www.ams.org/notices/201402/rnoti-p169.pdf). There seem to be a cyclic sieving phenomenon on ASM,
but they write that they have no idea what the q-statistic is.
However, the CSP might give a lead.