# "quantum" symmetric plane partitions beget alternating sign matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux, q-analogs

The "quantum" version **qTSPP** of the number of *totally symmetric plane partitions*, contained in the cube $[0,n]^3$, is enumerated by
$$f_n(q):=\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{k=1}^j\prod_{\ell=1}^k\frac{1-q^{j+k+\ell-1}}{1-q^{j+k+\ell-2}}.$$
L'Hopital $f_n(1)=\lim_{q\rightarrow1}f_n(q)$ restores the classical version $\prod_{1\leq\ell\leq k\leq j\leq n}\frac{j+k+\ell-1}{j+k+\ell-2}$. Although $f_n(-1)=0$ trivially, when $n$ is odd, I observe the case $n$ even is decidedly striking; namely that,
$$f_{2n}(-1)=\lim_{q\rightarrow -1}f_{2n}(q)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(3k+1)!}{(n+k)!},$$
the number $A_n$ of $n\times n$ *Alternating Sign Matrices* or $ASMs$.

> **QUESTION still waiting for an answer.**
>
> Is there a non-analytic (more conceptual) reason for this connection between **qTSPP** and **ASMs**?

Comment: Maybe it is related to this question?
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247965/is-this-a-q-count-of-alternating-sign-matrices/248016

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I'm encouraged by the comments there, including yours. Perhaps there is hope for my question then.

Comment: Your conjecture is a nice example of Stembridge's $q=-1$ phenomenon, not that this observation helps with a proof.

Comment: @RichardStanley: Thank you. I'm hopeful someone succeeds with a proof, my argument for this result is L'Hopital and algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Curiosity asking: Is there even such a thing as "quantum symmetric plane partitions" known? I understand that $f_n(q)$ is a natural way to quantize the generating series, but do we know a statistic on symmetric plane partitions that the yields this series as generating function? (Sorry if this is something well-known.)

Comment: Instead of $\sum_{\pi}1$, you do the weighted sum $\sum_{\pi}q^{\vert\pi\vert}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4384

Comment: Oh, that's a very simple statistic :) Nice! I only knew the $3n+1$ particular case of the formula...

Comment: @darijgrinberg: See also section 6 of the survey paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05934v2.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan @darijgrinberg: Note that, according to equation (6.5) of that survey paper of Krattenthaler's, we have $f_n(q) = \sum_{\pi} q^{|\pi|_0}$, sum over TSPP $\pi$ in a $n \times n \times n$ box. Here $|\pi|_0 = \sum_{1\leq i \leq j} \pi_{i,j}$ (definition on previous page). So this is not the usual weight $|\pi|$ but a kind of ``half'' weight.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to the question per se (in that it is not conceptual), but I wanted to point out that this $q=-1$ evaluation was essentially already observed in [Stembridge's original paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(94)90112-0) about the $q=-1$ phenomenon (as hinted at by the comment of Richard Stanley). Indeed, the point of that paper is that if $G$ is a subgroup of $S_3$ acting on plane partitions, and $P'_G(q)$ is the "appropriate" $q$-analog generating function for the plane partitions invariant under $G$, then the number of plane partitions invariant under $G$ and also self-complementary is $P'_G(-1)$. A particular case is $G=S_3$, which then says that the evaluation of the $q$-analog of the number of totally symmetric plane partitions at $q=-1$ is the number of totally symmetric, self-complementary plane partitions. You ask about alternating sign matrices rather than TSSCPPs, but of course the number of ASMs and TSSCPPs is the same.